# Django app hosting thorugh public ip not working when connected through DNS service

Tags: python, django, dns, host, public

I've hosted a Django app through my public ip like so 12.123.123.123:8080

My ISP provide a free .st domain to which I've connected to ip and port.

So mywebsite.st is hosting 12.123.123.123:8080. This DNS service has always worked when using node.js.

When someone connects to my public ip it works. The cmd shows:

"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 85

When someone uses my website i get:

"GET // HTTP/1.1" 404 75

and the website blanks

Here's my ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '12.123.123.123', 'www.mywebsite.st']

What's the deal? The DNS literally connects to my ip so I don't understand why it would be an issue.

Comment: did u do sudo reboot or restart your apache server after doing the changes?

Comment: i'm not sure if I even use apache.. is it standard/included in django? If so i'm not sure how to restart it